# Is it possible to change settings of another session in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to change settings of another session in Postgresql?

For example: alter session "pid" set name to value.

TIA

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by that? What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: No, it's not possible